# Azure Pipeline Publish Artifact - Artifact Name

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

In My Azure Pipeline, I am giving Build number format as `Build_$(Date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(Rev:.rr)` which gives my build number as Build_2019.04.04.05.

I want to use same in **Artifact Name property in Publish Artifact task**. When I give

Artifact Name: `Build_$(Date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(Rev:.rr)` it is not working.

In logs it says invalid special characters in artifact name and it keeps on re-trying for few times.

How to make it work?

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to 4c74356b41. I gave like below and it is working fine now

Artifact Name: `$(Build.BuildNumber)`

Comment: Thanks Shayki for edit..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that that particular format is only allowed in the build name, can you try and use $(Build.BuildNumber) instead? that's an automatic variable that contains current build number. that should work.

ps. I dont think thats a good idea, because that way you'd have to account for that when pulling this artifact.

Comment: Wow worked like a charm. For now we are planning manually pulling the artifact to temporary folder and deploy to servers. I will again update this when we work on auto pull and release to server.